# GUI View Hierarchy not always visible

Tags: ios, xcode6

I recently heard about this GUI view hierarchy in Xcode. And I have used it many times. But I sometimes when I run the app, the button is not there at all.

Can anyone please tell me when exactly will the button be visible when debugging??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only iOS 8 or better targets (simulator or hardware) get the button . You won't see it for an iOS 7 target.